# ubuntu 18.10 curl not finding openssl

Tags: 18.10, curl, openssl

curl is not working.

openssl version
OpenSSL 1.1.0h  27 Mar 2018

curl --version
curl: /usr/local/lib/libssl.so.1.1: version `OPENSSL_1_1_1' not found (required by /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcurl.so.4)

lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 18.10
Release:    18.10
Codename:   cosmic

Using Synaptic, I have reinstalled both curl and openssl and get the same error.

after removing openssl from /usr/local/bin - openssl doesn't work:

openssl  --version

openssl: /usr/local/lib/libcrypto.so.1.1: version `OPENSSL_1_1_1' not found (required by openssl)

openssl: /usr/local/lib/libcrypto.so.1.1: version `OPENSSL_1_1_0i' not found (required by /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libssl.so.1.1)

openssl: /usr/local/lib/libcrypto.so.1.1: version `OPENSSL_1_1_1' not found (required by /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libssl.so.1.1)

whereis openssl

openssl: /usr/bin/openssl /usr/include/openssl /usr/share/man/man1/openssl.1ssl.gz

So, curl is working, but only if it isn't using openssl.

Comment: It looks like the issue is some 3rd party software (from outside the Ubuntu repositories) that has installed a version of libssl.so in `/usr/local/lib` which is being used in preference to the version installed via Synaptic

Comment: Thanks. I removed openssl in /usr/local/bin, uninstalled ruby-build and curl, reinstalled ruby-build (but not curl). This installed curl:i386 -which works.

Answer (score 1):

This will help without reinstall:

```
sudo cp -f /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcrypto.so.1.1 /usr/local/lib/
sudo cp -f /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libssl.so.1.1 /usr/local/lib/
sudo ln -sfn /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcrypto.a /usr/local/lib/
sudo ln -sfn /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libssl.a /usr/local/lib/
sudo ln -sfn /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libssl.so.1.1 /usr/local/lib/
```

Comment: Can you elaborate on what this commands do?

Comment: Helping to find missing libs by copying them into /usr/local/lib/ and creating symbolic links. Worked for me just now